# 3 forms for create object rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Data collection for filling the order is going to table with 3 pages (go to each at the touch of a button). Stored in the database they need only after you press the last button. How to store data from the first to the last page?

1 page

```
<%= form_for(@orders) do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :city,placeholder: "city"%>

    <%= f.submit "next", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

2 page. After selecting the city made a request to the database on the first page, and select objects that have the city (which was selected on page 1)

```
<%= form_for(@orders) do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :time, placeholder: "time" %>

    <%= f.submit "next", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

3 page. Here we analyze the collected data with the first and second page and look for the tours that match the conditions

```
<%= form_for(@orders) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :trip, placeholder: "trip" %>

    <%= f.text_field :count, placeholder: "numver" %>

    <%= f.text_field :phone,placeholder: "phone"%>

    <%= f.submit "Order", class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

And only now, after completing 3 forms need to create an object in the database filled with fields that we have defined in all these three forms

It can store and transmit variables or hash from form to form?

Comment: Instead of creating three separate forms it would be wise to use the one 3 step form, using tab-content and tab-pane. [Muti-step form](http://azmind.com/demo/bootstrap-multi-step-registration-form/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating single multi-step form and then submit a form to the server just once after the all the steps are complete.

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
  var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
          allWells = $('.setup-content'),
          allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

  allWells.hide();

  navListItems.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
              $item = $(this);

      if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
          navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
          $item.addClass('btn-primary');
          allWells.hide();
          $target.show();
          $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
      }
  });

  allNextBtn.click(function(){
      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
          curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
          nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
          curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
          isValid = true;

      $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
          if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
              isValid = false;
              $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
          }
      }

      if (isValid)
          nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
  });

  $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
body {
    margin-top:40px;
}
.stepwizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.stepwizard-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.stepwizard {
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
.stepwizard-row:before {
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;
}
.stepwizard-step {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  
<div class="stepwizard col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
        <p>Step 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
        <p>Step 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
        <p>Step 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 1</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input  maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"  />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
            <textarea required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your address" ></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 2</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address"  />
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 3</h3>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  
</div>
```

See this fiddle for complete details. https://jsfiddle.net/kv23y6b4/

Comment: This is actually one form (see there is only one form tag). But that has been divided into three steps.